# find differenence in 2 mysql db from same server having same tables using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

program is to find difference in 2 db from same server having same tables and to display the difference in tables using php. Here I am finding difficulty to select dbnames ,i was trying to get dbnames through form method .

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Connecting db</title>
<style>
table, th, td {
     border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form  method="post" action="" >
  <label>db1 :</label>
  <input  type="text" name="db1 name">
  <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  <br><br>
  <label>db2 :</label>
  <input  type="text" name="db2 name">
  <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "db";

$db1 = $_POST["db1 name"];
$db2 = $_POST["db2 name"];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT application_id,application_name\n"
    . "FROM "($db1)".applications\n"
    . "WHERE(\n"
    . " application_id NOT IN \n"
    . " (SELECT application_id FROM "($db2)".applications)\n"
    . " )\n"
    . "GROUP BY application_id LIMIT 0, 30 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table><tr><th>APPLICATION ID</th><th>APPLICATION Name</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["application_id"]."</td><td>".$row["application_name"].."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this kind of connection

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password");
mysqli_select_db("db1",$conn);
mysqli_select_db("db2",$conn);
```